# Understanding the keras input_shape for Conv1D, Dense layers (1-dimensional input)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape, autoencoder

Folks!

I try to implement my first own dl-net in `keras` which will be an **auto-encoder** (hopefully de-noising and stacked). But I struggle with the input shape format of my input layer, which can be an `Conv1D` or `Dense`Layer (currently it's a `Dense` layer because I hoped that will fix the problem) - I also tried `pytorch` but this did not solve my issue either.

The underlying problem is that I feel as I don't get the input shape argument and its structure. For images you find great and logical explanations all over the internet. But as I use **1-dimensional data**, these techniques could not applied here - also the `Dense`/`Conv1D` API do not answer my question properly.

I have **7000 samples** where each is represented by a **1-D array of 500 integers**, thats is no additional feature dimensions or properties - just **one channel** if i understood correctly. Therefore `input_shape=(,500)` should work fine as i don't have to state the *batch size*.
But it does not work, I just get the message that my incoming data and the shape mismatch.

**Maybe someone can clear that up?** Maybe my input data is *shaped incorrect* - how should the numpy input look like? Or is my *layer misconfigured*?

Thank you in advance! I really tried to wrap my head around this and already tried several reshaping or input shape definitions - unfortunately nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot about "channels" dimension. Like an image, a sequence can also have channels.

For example you can run the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(input_shape=(500,), kernel_size=3, filters=2)
sample = tf.ones((1, 500, 1), dtype=tf.float32)  # (bs, input_shape, channels)

out = layer(sample)  #  out.shape will be (1, 498, 2)
```